# Need help to setup Kotlin in AndroidStudio2.3.3

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-studio-2.3, kotlin-android-extensions

In my Android Studio 2.3.3 I have installed Kotlin plugin and then created a kotlin class activity. When I comple and run for that Activity I am getting ClassNotFoundException. I confirm that I have added the new Activity in the manifest file for sure.

I am trying Kotlin with Android for the first time and not sure if anything need to change in gradle file or not for using Kotlin.

Below is my error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.chandan.myapplication, PID: 16035
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chandan.myapplication/com.example.chandan.myapplication.RegistrationActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.chandan.myapplication.RegistrationActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.chandan.myapplication.RegistrationActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.chandan.myapplication-xkv2k_8ODBWxxa3Gsn-HDw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the kotlin plugin to the root project build.gradle and app-module build.gradle.

Follow below url for detailed info:-

http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2017/06/setup-kotlin-plugin-for-android-studio.html

Comment: yes. That build.gradle things were missing. Thanks a lot.